# Chain Rule concepts and Integration notation

Tags: derivatives, indefinite-integrals, chain-rule

I am currently learning Calculus on my own and I ran into two simple doubts, I am sorry if the doubt is too easy, but bear with me because I am still learning

1. *When do we use the chain rule?*

   By definition, we are told we use chain rule when differentiating a compound function, being in the 
   format of  f(g(x))
   Example:

   $$f(x) = x²$$
    $$g(x) = 2x + 3$$
    $$f(g(x)) = (2x + 3)²$$

   In the example above it makes sense to use the chain rule, but what if I had another example like 
   this:

   $$f(x) = 2x$$
    $$g(x) = 3x + 3$$
    $$f(g(x)) = 2(3x + 3) = 6x + 6$$

   Clearly, in that case, we don't have two use the chain rule, right? Still, it is a compound function, or isn't it?
2. Is the below notation valid?

$$ f(x) = 2x² + 2 $$
$$ f'(x) = 4x $$
$$F(x) = \int f´(x)dx = f(x)$$
    Because sometimes I see:

$$\int f(x)dx $$

And it gets me confused because we are never integrating f(x) but its derivative, right?

Thanks in advance, guys

Comment: The function $f(x)=x$ can also be considered a composition of the functions $g(x)=x$ and $h(x)=1$. You don't need to use the chain rule because the composition is as simple as it is, but the rule still applies. In your example, take $u=3x+3$. Then$$\frac{\mathrm df(g(x))}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm du}\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{\mathrm d(2u)}{\mathrm du}\frac{\mathrm d(3x+3)}{\mathrm dx}=2\cdot3=6$$

Comment: By definition, $\int f(x)dx$ is a function whose derivative is $f(x)$.

Comment: @cxh007: just to add, the notation represents a class of functions whose derivative is $f(x) $. Thats the origin of constant of integration.